# sdigit function in c what is wrong with my code ?

Tags: c

*What  is wrong with my  code ? Even when i input a digit bewteen 1-10  or anything else it goes straight to  " you did not enter a correct  number "*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

 int main()
 {
  // CREATE A VARIABLE TO  STORE A RANDO NUMBER ITS TIME THE PROGRAM   RUNS

  int numdef, randomnum ;

  //ASSIGN RANDOM NUMBER
   numdef = (rand() % 11);

   //PROMT USER TO  GUESS A NUMBER BETWEEN 1-10
   printf("Please enter a number between 1-10\n");
   scanf("%d", &randomnum);


   // USE  SDIGIT  TO  VERIFY  THAT USER ENTERS A DIGIT

    if (isdigit(randomnum))


          printf("correct");

    // LET  HIM  KNOW IF HE IS CORRECT  OR NOT

     else

printf("\nYou did  not enter a correct  number FOOL!!!,please  try again! \n");


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Because `isdigit()` checks if the passed value is an ascii code for a digit or not. You are passing a number to it, so it gives `0` all the time.

The `isdigit()` checks if the value of `x` satisfies `'0' < x < '9'`, where `'0'` and `'9'` are the ascii values for the characters `0` and `9` respectively `48` and `57`.

You are reading a number with `scanf()` you don't need to check if *it's a number*. It has to be provided that `scanf()` succeeded, to verify that you must check the return value of `scanf()`, it is the number of successfuly scanned place holders.

So in your case

```
if (scanf("%d", &randomnum) != 1) // The 1 is for the lonely "%d"
    printf("Error, the text entered is not a number\n");
else
    printf("You entered `%d'\n", randomnum);

// Trying to read from `randomnum' here is dangerous unless it was
// initialized before `scanf()'.
```

Comment: Thank you   very  much  for your reply .  The thing is that i am doing an exercise. So even though  that there are other ways  , i need to use "isdigit"  specifically  to  check  if user has entered a digit .  Besides,  i would expect  that if i give a "5" for example would take it as true . But it doeasnt happpen.